# CakePHP redirect after Post

Tags: php, cakephp, post

i'm working on a CakePHP 2.x Plugin for JobOffers. For deleting the Jobs in the admin panel I have following ctp:

```php
<form method="post" action="/path/to/controller/action/<?php echo $offer['JobOffer']['id']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="data[id]" value="<?php echo $offer['JobOffer']['id']; ?>">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
</form>
```

With that form i call this action:

```php
public function office_delete($id = null) {
  if($this->request->is('post')) {
    $offerId = $this->request->data('id');

    if ($this->JobOffer->delete($offerId)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash('Joboffer deleted.', 'success');
    }
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
  }
  else {
    $this->reportErrors($this->JobOffer->validationErrors, "JobOffer not deleted.");
}
```

This action is working, but it does not redirect after deleting the joboffer. In debug mode it just sends some messages (related to the Model) but with a blank page.

I also tried it with referer().

The router looks like that:

```
Router::connect(
  '/path/to/action/:id',
  array(
    'plugin' => 'job_offers',
    'controller' => 'job_offers',
    'action' => 'delete',
    'office' => true)
);
```

Anybody?

Comment: Are you sure you can access `name=data[id]` by `$this->request->data('id')`? [Manual says](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#Cake\Network\Request::data) you need to prefix `id` with your model name. I have no knowledge of CakePHP. Also your errors are only displayed if the request method is not post. You might want to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I can access the post data (id) and work with it. Just the redirect is not working. Thanks for the hint with exceptions. I have some more errormessages, but removed them for readability.

Comment: `action="/path/to/co...` - that's not a good habit.

Comment: yes i know, but <form method="post" action="<?=Router::url(array('action' => 'office_delete'))?>"> is not working. The form points to http://dev.mydomain/office/job_offers/job_offers/delete and not to the right controller :/